# Install Splunk Universal Forwarder to OpenShift

Tags: openshift, splunk

I tried googling it but without any luck, also I tried searching official mailing lists, but also without any information.

Is it possible to install Splunk Universal Forwarder to OpenShift platform?

Comment: curious if you are still looking on getting logs to splunk from openshift, we have build a ready to use applications for monitoring openshift (metrics and logs forwarding), you can find more details on https://www.outcoldsolutions.com
FYI: I am original author of Splunk Logging Driver and original Splunk Docker Images.